# Can I do it with QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am student and I have a project, I need to find the important places like schools, supermarkets, restaurants, etc. in a 63 different areas to find a place for the new ATM..
Note that each area is a circle of 1Km radius.
Is there a tool to find a number of things in a specific area?
What does the QGIS have to solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response.   I tried to use google maps with a tool for specifying a circle on the map, but the procedure is very tedious and takes a lot of time..I was wondering if there is a tool in QGIS that can be helpful..

Comment: Have you been taught about GIS? QGIS can definitely do this but you need to learn how to read data, create a buffer, and do an overlay. Do you have the data? In what form? Please read the basic QGIS documentation, try something, ask here only if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS:

Import your data with your important places. OpenStreetMap maybe a good source, because you already have there schools, restaurants, etc.

Import or create a layer with the central location of each area.

Create the circles for each area using Vector → Geoprocessing tools → Fixed Distance buffer.

Use Vector → Analysis tools → Count points in polygon to get a new layer with a property with the number of "important places" in each area.